# Could not convert string to float error in pyhton

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

heres the code

```
#l is a list that stores all the GPAs of 10 students
l = []
#iterates the loop to collect GPAs of 10 members in the class
for i in range(1, 11):
   j = int(float(input()))  #this is where the error is
   l.append(j)
#find the average GPA of the class and store the average in the "result" variable
result = sum(l)/10
#printing the result
print("Average is: ",result)
```

at first it was j=int(input) and that was also giving an error. im new to python

Comment: Whether there's an error or not will depend on what's inputted. E.g. `4.5` will be ok, but `4,5` or `John` will produce errors.

Comment: I did not get to input anything.

Comment: Maybe you pressed Enter as soon as you were asked for input? Note that because there's no message, it may not be obvious when you're expected to enter something. Try `j = int(float(input("Enter value: ")))`.

Comment: `j=int(input())` (with `()`after `input`) is ok if the user is expected to enter integers. But again, if you press enter without inputting anything, an empty character cannot be converted to int or float.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, it works without any problem!
You have to give each value in the terminal and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to convert that input to float ? All you need is  check the input that can be convert to int with try and expect then when you Division a number every time you getting floating point number and I run your code it's working can you edit your questions and put the error there

```
score_list =[]

for num in range(10):
    number = int(float(input("enter a number")))
    score_list.append(number)
    
results = sum(score_list)/len(score_list)
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

For input validation. Start with a `try` `except` block.

```py
for i in range(0, 3):
  n = input('Enter a value..\n')
  while type(n) is not float:
    try:
      float(n)
      break
    except ValueError:
      n = input('Try again..\n')
  #append
```